# Conflict between textpos and tikz in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, textpos

I want to draw an arrow from one place on a slide to another. This works nicely:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Foo}
    Point\tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (j1) {}; here.
    
    Next line.
  \end{block}
 
  \vspace{2cm}

  Look\tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (j2) {}; there
 
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw [->,thick](j2) -- (j1);
  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get a slide with this contents:

[image: Desired image]

But to facilitate placement, I wrap the `block` inside a `textblock*` environment thus:

```
\begin{textblock*}{3cm}(1cm,1.5cm)
\begin{block}{Foo}
  Point\tikz[remember picture] \node[coordinate] (j1) {}; here.

  Next line.
\end{block}
\end{textblock*}
```

And now my arrow is partially hidden:

[image: Wrong picture]

Apparently the `textblock*` is drawn on top of the arrow. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the problem by using `textpos` without the `overlay` option:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{textblock*}{3cm}(1cm,1.5cm)
\begin{block}{Foo}
  Point\tikzmark{j1} here.

  Next line.
\end{block}
\end{textblock*}
 
  \vspace{2cm}

  Look\tikzmark{j2} there
 
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw [->,thick](pic cs:j2) -- (pic cs:j1);
  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works nicely. However, I noticed that the `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}` is vital for your solution to work. Otherwise, the text box simply disappears.

Comment: @oz1cz It does not disappear as such, it is just hiding behind the background canvas :)